# How to find strings between "-" in array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to get each string between "-" from the array below

```
array(2) {     
[0]=> string(75) "2225-Fried chicks-PTB001-1-potato",        
[1]=> string(72) "2226-Fried pig-PTB002-3-potato" }
```

so I can explode it to:

```
$id=2225;    
$food=Fried chicks;    
$barode= PTB001;    
$qty=1;    
$salad=potato;
```

What would be the fastes way?

Comment: Show us your best attempt.

Comment: you answered your own question when you wrote: _"So I can `explode` it to"_, RTFM: [`explode` is a function](http://www.php.net/explode)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foreach ($array as $a) {
  list($id, $food, $barode, $qty, $salad) = explode('-', $a);
}
```

Comment: smart one, I will accept it as correct in 4 min, thanks mate !